# Google cloud function authorization

Tags: ruby, google-cloud-platform

I have a google cloud function that I can invoke using `gcloud` cli using a service account with the necessary IAM permissions

```
gcloud auth activate-service-account 'service-account-email' --key-file=google_key.json

gcloud functions call opt_manual --data '{some-json}'
```

this works just fine.

I'm trying to implement a similar call using official ruby sdk https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-ruby/tree/main/google-cloud-functions-v1

```rb
name = "opt_manual"
data = '{some-json}'

client = ::Google::Cloud::Functions::V1::CloudFunctionsService::Client.new do |config|
  config.credentials = "google_key.json"
end

client.get_function ::Google::Cloud::Functions::V1::GetFunctionRequest.new(name: name) 

# =>
# Permission denied on resource project opt_manual.. debug_error_string:{
#   "created":"@1636730694.210272000",
#   "description":"Error received from peer ipv4:142.251.36.202:443",
#   "file":"src/core/lib/surface/call.cc",
#   "file_line":1070,
#   "grpc_message":"Permission denied on resource project opt_manual.",
#   "grpc_status":7
# } (Google::Cloud::PermissionDeniedError)
```

The service account includes the following permissions:

- Cloud Functions Admin
- Cloud Functions Invoker
- Service Account User
- Workload Identity User

Cloud function principles include correct service account.

Despite all of that I'm still getting `PermissionDeniedError` maybe someone had a similar case and remember how it could be fixed? Keep in mind in the same project I access bigquery and cloud storage using official SDK using the same service account without any problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you replace the following with values and try it instead of `opt_manual`:

`projects/{project}/locations/{location}/functions/opt_manual`

Your Service Account likely has too many permissions. You should need only Cloud Functions Invoker (`roles/cloudfunctions.invoker`).

**Explanation** the underlying method call is [projects.locations.functions.get](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.locations.functions/get). Unfortunately, the Ruby API documentation for [GetFunctionsRequest](https://googleapis.dev/ruby/google-cloud-functions-v1/latest/Google/Cloud/Functions/V1/GetFunctionRequest.html) doesn't explain this. [APIs Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer) is the definitive tool for understanding Google's REST APIs.

Comment: This did the trick :)